# Changing the Data Format that is received from the backend in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I'm currently receiving date from the backend where I'm showing it on the UI.

These are how the dates look on the backend:

[image]

And this is how the date looks when I fetch it on the UI:

[image]

As you might have noticed, there is an unnecessary 'T0' which is being shown on the frontend. Is there a way to remove that?

Here is the code where I'm directly getting the data in my state:

```
   class RecNotification extends Component {
    state = {
       clickedDate: this.props.data.status_submit_timestamp,
        ...
   }
```

And I'm directly showing it on my UI in the return part of the code like this:

```
    {
                        this.state.status === true ?
                            <>
                                <small class="float-right" style={{ color: '#0d9242' }}><b>
                                    {this.state.clickedDate}</b>
                                </small>
                                <small class="float-right" style={{ color: '#0d9242', marginRight: 3 }}><b>
                                    Accepted
                                </b></small>
                            </>
                            :
                            <></>
                    }
```

I want the date to be like this '2021-04-23 8:30:11' instead of this '2021-04-23T08:30:11'. I want to remove the T0.

**Edit**

Here is the edited code based on Dhaval's and Felipe's answer and it's working now:

```
  class RecNotification extends Component {
    state = {
       clickedDate: this.props.data.status_submit_timestamp,
        ...
   }


   formatedDate = (date) => {
    return date.charAt(11) === '0' ? date.replace('T0'," ") : date.replace('T'," ");
  };


   <small class="float-right" style={{ color: '#dc3545' }}><b>
                                  {this.formatedDate(this.state.clickedDate)}</b>
                                </small>
                                <small class="float-right" style={{ color: '#dc3545', marginRight: 3 }}><b>
                                    Declined
                                </b></small>
```

Comment: you can use `moment` library and do like moment(yourDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a util function to split the date on the "TO" and then format as you want.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clickedDate: "2021-04-23T08:30:11",
  };

  formatedDate = (date) => {
    return date.charAt(10) === 'T' ? date.replace('T', " ") : date;
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.formatedDate(this.state.clickedDate)}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this won't work in the case where i have string with `T1`

Comment: Edited your answer with my condition

Comment: I just tried this but T0 is remaning as it is.

Comment: @Filipe It'll work because it's ternary operator , just understand my condition.

Comment: @ShridharK Try the answer I've posted or the answer I've edited of filipe

Comment: I tried exactly that but isn't working. I'll post the edited code.

Comment: I've posted the edited code. You can look into it. Unfortunately, it still isn't working.

Comment: My bad! Your code is working as well. I added the function at the wrong place.

Comment: The code 'works' but is it the right way of doing it? What if in future you need to change the format to dd-mm-yyy or mmmm dd, yy. Suggest you all to put a thought into this.

Comment: @ManuSharma Better to don't replace  08 with 8, I suggest to just replcae T with whitespace, what you think ?

Comment: @Manu Sharma I'll revert back to your code if in the future I change the dateformat ;) Thanks for all your inputs. I have to understand Dhaval's code now. I'm new to React

Answer (score 2):

I see answers suggesting splitting the timestamp string with the 'T0' delimiter which can work but won't be the right way of doing it.

To handle the time in JS, we can use some node packages like moment. In this case since your requirement is just to format the timestamp string, you can use 'dateformat'.

```
1. npm install dateformat
2. import dateFormat from 'dateformat';

dateFormat("2021-04-23T08:30:11", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")
```

Working example: [date format](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-hooks-k3jsl?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do this in React?

Comment: The link I have added is from a sample react project itself.

Comment: Thanks this is working. In the state itself I used the dateformat function.

Answer (score 0):

### Better solution by example

```
let str = '2021-04-23T08:30:11';

str.charAt(11) === '0' ? str.replace('T0'," ") : str.replace('T'," ");

console.log(str); //2021-04-23 8:30:11
```